# What should be return value from ShellCommandPrecondition of AWS data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I am writing one shell script which should get executed by `ShellCommandPrecondition` of AWS data pipeline. AWS documentation doesn' specify

1. What should be the return value from the script?
2. Can I just return 0 on success and 1 or any other value if condition does not meet? AWS documentation says `pipeline runs activity when precondition is true` not sure how to return `true` from the shell script
3. How return values are treated by the pipeline?
4. At which interval (1 second, 1 minute, 1 hour) precondition execution is retried by the pipeline?

Goal of my task is to create a pipeline which should run once in a month and only when this precondition is true.

Comment: I recently asked AWS support the same question, and it turned out that `ShellCommandPrecondition` works like this: script just executes `retry attempts` times till the successful output (e.g. no exit calls), with `retry period` pauses between executions. if no successful output has been received - pipeline just fails and should be restarted. In my case it was impossible to achieve the goal with `ShellCommandPrecondition`, so, take a look at [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish this was mentioned in AWS documentation. They have left documentation half baked which makes many things difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, when ShellCommandPrecondition provided script is executed, this must finish with a successful process termination, i.e. no error exit code.

In reference to points `1 & 2`, If the script is run successfully, or your force the exit with 0 as return code, the *ShellCommandPrecondition* will be assumed as `True`.

Again from comments,  for the `3rd question`, the delay between retries can be set with the [`retryDelay`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandprecondition.html) parameter.